# Java - "local variable is not used"

Tags: java, variables, local-variables

I have this problem where I initialize a variable outside of a forloop. And then inside of the forloop try to update the value of this variable but everytime I "local variable not used". I tried a simple example (below) and the problem is still there. Ret is highlighted in my compiler and the error message is displayed. I don't understand why I can't access variables inside my loops anymore. Is this possibly due to me missing a bracket somewhere in my methods somewhere else in the class?

```
public static String test(String input) {
        String ret = "";
        for(int i=0;i<5; i++) {
            ret += "m";
        }
        return "";
        
    }
```

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: use it in return statement `return ret;`

Comment: One question: why do did you declare `ret`? And why are you modifying it?

Comment: It is a warning not an error.  I think it is telling you that you are computing something in `ret` and throwing it away rather than returning it (as I think you intended).  So maybe you should pay attention :-)

Comment: FWIW - I don't get this message when compiling with `javac` (Java 8).

Comment: Why do you return ""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error message because you are building the ret variable but you are not using it. For example if you use the variable in an if statement you will not get the error anymore.

```
public static String test(String input) {
    String ret = "";
    for(int i=0;i<5; i++) {
        ret += "m";
    }
    if (ret.equals("mmmmm")){
       ret +="";
    }
    return "";
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your IDE or compiler is noticing that you build up text in the local var `ret` but you never use that text. That built-up text is discarded, and you return an empty string. Your tools are alerting you to this nonsense.

Also, you make no use of the argument passed to your static method, more nonsense.